# Sidebar in blazor server

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to create a right sidebar in blazor. Given my very limited knowledge in HTML this is what I came up with so far...

```
@if(!MyMenu.IsEditMenuCollapsed){
<div class="@MyMenu" style="width:30%; right:0">
    <label>Name</label>
    <DxTextBox></DxTextBox>
</div>
}

@code {
    EditMenuBar MyMenu = new EditMenuBar();
}
```

The sidebar is supposed to open after a click on a DataGrid, but it wont. Can anyone help me?

Also Code improvements are greatly apreciated.

Comment: There is no question here. Does it work? If not, what does happen?

Comment: Edited the question. I hope it's now understandable. The sidebar is supposed to open, but it wont.

Comment: Two possible issues: 1) "MyMenu.isEditMenuCollapsed" doesn't seem like proper C# convention, so maybe there's a typo and it should be "MyMenu.IsEditMenuCollapsed", or 2) values for id and css seem to be swapped.

Comment: @brudert 1) I changed it to MyMenu.IsEditMenuollapsed, didn't change the outcome
2) What do you mean by "values seem to be swapped"? Sorry, if this is a stupid or unnecessary question

Comment: @Daniel - in your <div> tag, you have an "id" attribute and a "class" attribute. It looks like "@MyMenu.EditMenuCssClass" is a kind of "class" but you have it as a value for the "id" attribute. 

You also need an at (@) in front of the "if" block. So "@if (!MyMenu...)"

Comment: The @MyMenu.EditMenuCssClass is not a defined class of mine. It's from one of the tutorials I watched. Added the @ in first line.

Comment: @Daniel -- can you link to the tutorial? Providing more code and/or more information could help with the assessment. (could be issue with handling datagrid interaction, could be IsEditMenuCollapsed isn't being set correctly, etc.)